# Cordova AppCenter Plugin : Query fired: did not receive both families in time for in.appcenter.ms:443

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-app-center, capacitor

I have recently been working on migrating an app from Angular 5 to Angular 8, Ionic 3 to 4 and from Cordova to Capacitor and I encountered a very weird bug using the AppCenter App Analytics plugin for Cordova.

Before describing the issue and my thoughts about it, I just wanted to point out that I tested the plugin with Capacitor and that it is compatible.

After upgrading the application, I got the following issue:

```
2020-04-18 21:56:31.037967-0400 App[2339:416013] [] nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C1] Query fired: did not receive both families in time for in.appcenter.ms:443
```

that seems to be completely blocking my app. I could not find any explanation of this error message on the Internet, so I was wondering if someone would understand what does 'family' mean.

Also, another important point to note is that the bug seems to appear when the AppModule gets bootstrapped. Here is why:

I added a log in the main.ts file right before the bootstrap call:

[image]

This log does show up in the Xcode console:

[image]

I then placed a log at the beginning of the app component ts file and it won't show up.

I was wondering if anyone had the experience to know what that error means.

Thank you so much and have a great day!

Comment: Hi, have you solved that bug? Ive been dealing with it now.

Comment: Yes I actually had an issue with my app modules (some modules were made for a different ionic version. This error was not caused by appcenter on its own. Make sure that the plugins versions are compatible with the ionic version and let me know if iit helps you as well

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the feature you're using from App Center, give this [repo](https://github.com/capacitor-community/appcenter-sdk-capacitor) a look. There is a Capacitor community plugin available with support for App Center Analytics and Crashes.